# How I know which ns is firstly connected to my domain in multiple dns setup

Tags: domain-name-system, dns-hosting

My domain xyz.com is configured with 5 different ns in domain registrar control pannel.

```
such as
ns1.no-ip1.com
ns2.no-ip2.com
ns0.xyz.com
ns3.no-ip3.com
ns4.no-ip4.com
```

All ns are binded with same ip. How can I know which ns is first connected to my domain xyz.com?

so that I can change the ip for that to switch my domain to new server and leaving the rest on old server. if in case the new one is not working.

```
tracert can tell me route with hops but not the ns. 
nslookup can tell me which ip it is connected. but on my domain all are connected with same ip.
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no ordering to NS records (or any other type of DNS resource records). Nameservers might query any of them to get information about your domain.

Might I ask why you would have 5 nameservers that all point to the same IP address? It's pointless. You might as well just have one nameserver for your domain in that case.

Comment: I have no clue. It was setup by predecessors.

Comment: @user57221: Then - what do you really want to know or achieve with your question?

Comment: I need to point the domains to new server. I was thinking may be I will change one main ns to new server and if that will not respond my domains will be pointed to old server as alternative server without any problem.

Comment: If you have 5 nameservers one one of them doesn't respond, then, yes, it will query the other 4.